# Python modify single variable by reference

Tags: python, pass-by-reference

I have seen other questions related to this topic, but haven't really found an answer to the following simple problem:

**VB Code**:

> ```
> Function f_x(ByRef x As Integer)
>
>     x = x + 1
>
> End Function
>
> Sub test()
>
>     Dim w As Integer
>     w = 2
>
>     Call f_x(w)
>
>     MsgBox w
>
> End Sub
> ```

**The output above is 3**, whereby the variable "w" is modified through the pointer "x" inside the function "F_x()" (i.e. "by reference").

Can I write a similar function in Python, which modifies a single numerical variable through a pointer (i.e. "by reference")? I understand that a list or a Numpy array will be modified (automatically) by reference when passed to a function, but what about a single numerical variable?

**EDIT**: as per suggestion below, I am adding my attempt to code this in Python (which obviously doesn't work):

> ```
> def test_function(y):
>     y = y + 1
>
> x = 2 
> test_function(x) 
> print(x)
> ```

**The output above is 2**, not 3.

**Edit 2**: why on earth would anyone bother with choosing whether to pass a numerical variable by reference (through a pointer) or by value? What if the task is to write a computationally efficient code and one is dealing with large floating point numbers: here, a pointer ("by reference") will only need to store the memory address, whilst "by value" approach will have to "copy" the entire variable inside the function.

Comment: You should try to write it in Python and come here and ask when it doesn't work. Not post a VB code tagged as Python...

Comment: No, **python does not support call by reference**.

Comment: @Tomerikoo: ok I will do an edit to show my attempt.

Comment: I appreciate the question has been marked as duplicate: I have seen the other thread to which my question has been linked, but the thread suggests passing a tuple and other ways to go about the problem: it doesn't really give a solution to modifying a single variable by reference. That's why I asked a "new" question...

Comment: @JanStuller The simple answer is just "No, it's not possile". Python does not support something like VB's "ByRef ".

Comment: Because someone removed it, here is the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: Python doesn't support call by ref, but you could have a wrapper object for your variable. You can then pass the object to your function and the function has to modify your value. E.G. test_function(obj) where test_function executes: obj.y += 1

Comment: Why was this re-opened?  "whilst "by value" approach will have to "copy" the entire variable inside the function." **Python isn't call by value**. Did you **read the linked duplicate when I closed it originally**? Python does not copy an object when you pass it.

Answer (score 4):

You could put your variable in a mutable object like a dict:

```
def test_function(y):
    y['x'] = y['x'] + 1

d = {'x': 2} 
test_function(d) 
print(d['x'])
```

Primitive types are immutable.